# Python Dataframe Weird Grouping

Tags: python, pandas

I have data that has the following columns: state, gender, year, name, count, age

I want to drop the state column and reaggregate by having the sum of count. I used the following code:

```
name_df = name_df_state.drop(['state'],axis=1)
name_df = name_df.groupby(['gender','year','age','name'])['count'].sum()
```

But the issue with that is that it doesn't give me the gender, year, age, name in each row and it doesn't name the new count column. Essentially I want the pandas equivalent to:

```
select gender, year, name, age, sum(count) count
from table
group by gender, year, name, age
```

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use reset_index to make the dataframe look like your expected output.

```
name_df = name_df_state.drop(['state'],axis=1)
name_df = name_df.groupby(['gender','year','age','name'])['count'].sum()
```

Comment: Thank you! This was exactly what I was looking for!